# Random float in C#

Tags: c#, random, numbers

I need to generate a random number in C# for a program I'm writing. Let's say I need to generate a number between -3 and 3. I know I can generate an integer with

```
System.Random random = new System.Random(); 
float rndNumber = random.Next(-3, 4);
```

However, this only gives whole numbers (ex. -2, 1, 2, 0). This doesn't generate any decimals. Although you can generate decimals like this

```
var rand = new Random();
var rndNumber = new decimal(rand.NextDouble());
```

This gives decimals (ex. 0.47, 0.93, 0.58). But how would I generate numbers that aren't just a whole number? For example 1.04, 1.98, or -0.73 but no going under or over -3 and 3?

Comment: fyi `decimal` is not a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var rand = new Random(); 
    var rndNumber = new decimal(rand.NextDouble());
rndNumber = rndNumber * 6 - 3;
```

NextDouble() returns a double between 0 and 1 multiply this by the range you want 6 then shift it by the offset you.want -3

Comment: Works great! Is there a way to only generate the first 3 decimals?

Comment: You can use Math.Round pass the value in and the number of decimal places you want .... Math.Round(rndNumber, 3)